# Delete in Stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

My delete query does not work conditionaly, it deletes all the records from tne table

```
PROCEDURE          "SP_NEW"    (
logon_id        IN  VARCHAR2,
id      IN  VARCHAR2,
key     IN  VARCHAR2,
error_code      OUT NUMBER,
error_message       OUT VARCHAR2)

...
PROCEDURE delete_counts(str_logon_id IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM TMS_ENTITY_COUNT WHERE logon_id = str_logon_id;
END;

BEGIN;

delete_counts(logon_id);

END;
```

Please, help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My tms_entity_count has a few columns, one od them is user_logon_id. I try to delete records from this table which have values, specified by input paramter. If I use @str_logon_id and :str_logon_id the procedure is not compiled.  – Angela (3 mins ago)

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough info to go on, but I could make a couple guesses.

- Does `TMS_ENTITY_COUNT` have two columns named `logon_id` and `str_logon_id`? Are they both equal all the time?
- Depending on your flavor of SQL, do you need an @ or : symbol before your variable name as in `...WHERE logon_id =`**`@`**`str_logon_id`?

Comment: Thanks for the help.
My tms_entity_count has a few columns, one od them is user_logon_id.
I try to delete records from this table which have values, specified by input paramter. 
If I use @str_logon_id and :str_logon_id the procedure is not compiled.